# Operator precedence in C explanation

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
int x;
x=1%9*4/5+8*3/9%2-9;
printf("%d \n", x);
}
```

The output of the program is `-9`. When I tried to breakdown the code according to operator precedence`(*  /  %,Multiplication/division/modulus,left-to-right)` answer turns out to be `-8`.

Below is the breakdown of the code:

```
x=1%9*4/5+8*3/9%2-9;
x=1%36/5+24/9%2-9;
x=1%7+2%2-9;
x=1+0-9;
x=-8;
```

Can someone explain how the output is `-9`.

Comment: I get `1%9*4/5+8*3/9%2-9` to be `(1%9*4/5)+(8*3/9%2)-9`. Multiplication, division and modulo operators all have same [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and left-to-right associativity.

Comment: `void main` is wrong. `main` should return `int`.

Comment: Maybe you misinterpreted a precedence table that listed multiplication,division and modulus as three operators having the same precedence.

Comment: `1 % 9 * 4 / 5` is evaluated left-to-right; same precedence, so it is `((1 % 9) * 4) / 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you consider modulo to have lower precedence than multiplication and division, when in fact it does not. Instead of

```
x = (1 % ((9 * 4) / 5)) + (((8 * 3) / 9) % 2) - 9;
```

the expression you have really represents

```
x = (((1 % 9) * 4) / 5) + (((8 * 3) / 9) % 2) - 9;
```

The modulo in the first summand is applied before the multiplication and division.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 1%9*4/5+8*3/9%2-9
== 1*4/5+24/9%2-9
== 4/5+2%2-9
== 0+0-9
== -9
```

Comment: Adding an explanation how it is computed will help

Answer (score 1):

All these operators `*, /, %` belong to the category of multiplicative operators. Their grouping is more clearly described in the C++ Standard (the same is valid for the C Standard) 5.6 Multiplicative operators:

> 1 The multiplicative operators *, /, and % **group left-to-right**.

Thus this expression statement

```
x=1%9*4/5+8*3/9%2-9;
```

is equivalent to the following statement

```
x = (( ( 1 % 9 ) * 4 ) / 5 ) + ( ( ( 8 * 3 ) / 9 ) % 2 ) - 9;
```